# How can I make an exponentially curving object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I want to make a circle that curves down exponentially, like so: [image]

But I need it to be truly exponential. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the XYZ Math Surface available through the Extra Objects add-on to achieve this.

First, go into User Preferences, Add-ons, and search for Extra Objects. Enable it via the checkbox.

[image: enable extra objects]

Now you should have additional objects in your Add/Mesh menu - in particular the Math Function, XYZ Math Surface. The XYZ Math Surface allows you to set up how two variables - U and V - vary, and how the X, Y, Z coordinates are generated from these.

Set up the parameters in the Toolshelf (<kbd>T</kbd>) as shown below :

[image: exponential cone]

Here `U` varies from 0 to 2*pi with 128 steps - one whole rotation (in radians).

`V` varies from 0 to 2.10 with 32 steps - this is the distance from the centre.

The `X` coordinate is defined as `(v+0.1)*cos(u) + (v+0.1)*sin(u)` and `Y` as `-(v+0.1)*sin(u)+(v+0.1)*cos(u)` - this converts from the polar coordinates to X and Y.

The `Z` is calculated using an exponential function `-1/e**-(1.6-v)` (EDIT - this can be simplified to `e**(1.6-v)`).

Note the `+0.1` in each of the X and Y equations to offset the centre of the cone so we don't hit infinity (limits the inner edge). Also, adjusting the `1.6` in the Z equation adjusts the speed of the exponential falloff.

Comment: I have copied all of the settings, and my cone is all warped and sideways.

Comment: @GavinLoukusa - If you can take a screenshot of your settings and results and edit it into your question then I can take a look.

Comment: @GavinLoukusa I just spotted a couple of typos in the equations in my answer (they were correct in the image - just wrong in the text). If this doesn’t fix your problem then let me know and post a screenshot.